# Instrução "sarl" - Assembly

Tags: assembly

Tenho uma instrução `sarl $9, mem32`.

Sei que a instrução sarl, shifta para a direita um número determinado de bits (neste caso 8?) e sei que a var. "mem 32" tem uma dimensão de 32 bits e conteúdo -2048(base decimal).

Agora sabendo estes pontos, no geral e na prática não consigo desvendar o que esta operação faz.

Comment: Por que usou a tag C#? Aliás, qual "tipo" de assembly você está prgramando?